# WooCommerce Box Office - How to Check if Product is a Ticket PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

[Ticket Box is Checked IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBl6T.png)

The Box Office plugin adds this 'ticket' checkbox functionality to make a product a ticket. How do I check if the product is a ticket? I'm thinking it would go somewhat like `$product->is_ticket()`

Context - My website has removed the quantity field for all products. I want to enable the quantity field for only ticket products and have an if statement like `if($product->is_ticket()) {do this}`

Answer (score 0):

I just looked in the database and used get post meta function to see if == "yes"

Answer (score 0):

I know this is super old, but I ran across this question and the only answer available is super unhelpful (although technically correct once in context), so I thought I'd share my solution.

Get product object:

```
$product = wc_get_product($id);
```

Get Attributes:

```
$attributes = get_post_meta($product->get_id());
```

The 'Ticket' data is stored in this array. If it is a ticket, it will have a key-value pair `'_ticket' => array(0 => 'yes')`. So, a simple if statement will sort out ticket products:

```
if ($attributes['_ticket'][0] == 'yes'){
   //... do something to ticket products here
}
```